# Python function won't accept string as a parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to pass a string as a parameter to a function in python(2), but as i try to execute it, i get an error that says:

```
Error get_all_tweets expected a string or other character buffer object
```

This is my code:

```
def get_all_tweets(screen_name):

    consumer_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    consumer_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    access_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    access_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    alltweets = []
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name, count = 200)
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    try:
        with open('$screen_name.json', 'a') as f:
            f.write(alltweets)
            return True
    except BaseException as e:
        print ('Error get_all_tweets %s' % str(e))
    return True


get_all_tweets(str("BarackObama"))
```

I can't understand why i get a complaint about the parameter not being a string, which it clearly is. I am fairly new to python, but every resource i have come across states that this is the way to pass a string as a parameter.
Is there something i have overseen? I don't get any other errors.
I am using Python 2.7.12.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error message you wrote for yourself is misleading. Remove the try-except, and you'll get a much more useful error message.

Comment: Are you sure `f.write(alltweets)` isn't causing a failure? It's a list, after all. `file.write()` expects a string, and you're passing it a list. It's cases like this where you really should have used a debugger to step through line-by-line before even thinking of posting here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The weird error stems from you catching `BaseException`, something you should never ever do.

The true error is a `TypeError`: You trying to write a list to a file:

```
f.write(alltweets)
```

This won't work, because the write method of a file object only accepts strings or other character buffer objects as arguments.

The way to write a list to a file is by iterating over it:

```
for tweet in alltweets:
    f.write(tweet + "\n")
```

This will probably not work in your case, because I assume what tweepy returns as a tweet is a dictionary, not a simple string. In that case, use `json` to encode it:

```
import json
...
for tweet in alltweets:
    f.write(json.dumps(tweet) + "\n")
```

Comment: Yes, i see that now. Thank you for your tips. I just grabbed the piece of code from another post here on stack. I am very new to python and think in a java-way.

Comment: You could also do `f.write( "\n".join(alltweets) )` for a list instead of looping over it per this answer.

Comment: @Michael Right, but that depends both on the length of the list (if it's very long, might not want to create a very long string first), and whether it's a list at all (if it's a generator, my solution is lazy). I think simple iteration with a for loop is the most generally applicable way, and not much longer.

Comment: @L3viathan I wasn't sure if it would be more resource intensive to write to the file multiple times or to store a huge string in memory and then write it all at once, need to test it. I just wanted to let gerimash know that the `join()` function can do pretty much the exact same thing since he is new to python. Your method is the best to implement unless you are very confident that the variable will always be a list and relatively small one at that.

Comment: @Michael I doubt writing multiple files will be a performance hit; it'll be buffered anyways. But yes, `str.join` is useful to know.